# scons dylib dynamic linking on mac

Tags: macos, dynamic, scons, dylib

I want to link some dynamic libraries in my project with scons.

Example:

> source/main.cpp
>
> tool/lib/libboost_system.dylib

Binary Location

> source/progbinary

My problem is, after the link process, the binary can't find libboost_system.dylib

> dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_system.dylib

`otool -L` shows the problem. I can fix this with a little script that corrects the path. But I want to do this in scons.

On linux it is really easy I have only to set the `RPATH` in scons.

----- after the tip from @Brady

I add Linkflags for my library. After Linking I got the Error

> 'g++: error: -install_name only allowed with -dynamiclib'

So I add to the command

> LINKFLAGS = '-dynamiclib install_name @executable_path/libWhatever.dylib'

And now I get if I call my execute the message

> 'cannot execute binary file'

And

> otool -L

show me:

> @executable_path/tools/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
> libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)

the linking command from scons looks like:

> /opt/local/bin/g++ -o source/prog -dynamiclib -install_name @executable_path/tools/lib/libboost_system.dylib source/main.o -Ltools/lib -lboost_system

Comment: You need to get the command line options `-install_name @executable_path/libWhatever.dylib` to `ld`.  With `make` this would require setting `LDFLAGS`, however I don't know how to do it with `scons`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the comment provided above by [trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe): 
[scons dylib dynamic linking on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646206/scons-dylib-dynamic-linking-on-mac/19655163#comment29184418_19646206)

The following needs to be passed to the linker:

```
-install_name @executable_path/libWhatever.dylib
```

This can be done in SCons as follows:

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(LINKFLAGS = ['-install_name @executable_path/libWhatever.dylib'])
```

If you need to compile a dynamic (shared) library, it can be done with the [SharedLibrary() builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c602.html#AEN606).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem changed a little bit after using your advise. I edited the post above

Comment: @chak, I added info to the answer about compiling with shared libraries. Hopefully that will help. I dont know enough about compiling on mac to be able to help much more. If this doesnt work, you should consider asking another question about compiling on mac.